# analyzing convergence of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{x\sin x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I need to prove the convergence or divergence of

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{x\sin x} \ dx$$

but I don't need to calculate the exact value.

This is what I did:

$$0\le x\le\frac{\pi}{2}\implies 0\le x\sin x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

because $\sin(x)\le 1$, then:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\le \frac{1}{x\sin x}\le$$

hmmmm, I can't invert $0$, so I guess this is not the solution. In fact, this integral may diverge because of small values of $x$...

Well, if I do $x=\cos\theta$, then $dx = -\sin\theta d\theta$ and we have:

$$\int_{\arccos 0}^{\arccos \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{-\sin\theta}{\sin\theta\sin\theta} d\theta  = \int_{\arccos 0}^{\arccos \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin\theta} d\theta$$

which I also don't know if converge or not, I donm't even know how to integrate it.

Could somebody help me in bounding this integral or proving it diverges? If the integration is hard, I prefer to just prove by comparsion because I can't use advanced techniques

Comment: note that as $x\rightarrow 0$ your integrand behaves as $x^{-2}$ which tells you what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac1{\sin(x)}\geq1\implies \frac{1}{x\sin(x)}\geq\frac1x\qquad 0<x\leq\pi/2.$$

Comment: so it diverges because $\frac{1}{x}$ diverges, right?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Exactly

Comment: Sorry, this argumentation is wrong. Only a note: The divergence of the integrand says nothing about the integral. In your case: The integral diverges because of the divergence of $\ln x$.

Comment: @user90369 I understand "divergence of $1/x$" as "divergence of *the integral* of $1/x$"

Comment: The question of *Guerlando OCs* sounds different. I hope he hasn't misunderstood something. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$  \dfrac{1}{x\sin(x)} \ge \dfrac{1}{x*1} $$ since $ 0 \le\sin(x)\le 1 $ (in the given domain).

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{x}\le 1$ => $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x\sin x}\ge \frac{1}{x^2}$

=> $\enspace \displaystyle \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{x\sin x}\ge \lim_{h\to 0^+}\int\limits_h^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{x^2}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}(-\frac{1}{x})|_h^{\frac{\pi}{2}} =-\frac{2}{\pi}+\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{h}$

which is divergent